# c++ not validating string input

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int main() {
    Population town;
    int population;
    int numBirths, numDeaths;
    string city, intTest;
    bool isValid = true;

    do {
        cout << "Enter name of city: ";
        getline(cin, city);
        for (int i = 0; i < city.length(); i++) {
            if (!isalpha(city[i])) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while(!isValid);
```

Its not properly checking to see if the input is a string or not. Not sure whats wrong with the code.

Comment: What input did you try and what was the result?

Comment: `isValid = std::all_of(city.brgin(), city.end(), [](char ch) { return isalpha(ch)!=0; });`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(isalpha(city[i]))) {
   isValid = false;
}
else {
    isValid = true;
    break;
}
```

The first time this loop finds an alphabetic character, it will set `isValid` to true and then break out of the loop. As your code stands, `isValid` is true if there is **any** alphabetic character in the string and false otherwise after the loop.

You probably actually want something like:

```
string city; //populate this
bool isValid = true; //Innocent till proven guilty

do {
    city = ... ; //get new city
    isValid = true; //Don't forget to reset!!
    for (int i = 0; i < city.length(); i++) {
        if(!isalpha(city[i])) {
            isValid = false;
            break; //If we're invalid, doesn't matter what the rest is
        }
    }
while(!isValid);
```

---

Furthermore, for whatever reason, you're reading into `city` twice.

First you read a single word:

```
cin >> city;
```

and then you read a full line:

```
getline(cin, city);
```

If the city will only be a single word, use the first and delete the second. Otherwise, if the city will be multiple words (that the user will enter terminated by a newline (enter key)), delete the first and use the second.

Comment: @user8799094 I'm going to need a little more detail than that if you want help. The code I've posted is working fine for me. What is your input and what is your expected output vs. actual output? Does your input have a space? If so, remember that the space won't be an alphabetic character

Comment: So the program is suppose to only take in a string. If it has numbers or symbols in the word it's suppose to ask for the input again (jidnba21892) and keep asking until its a string. 2 word strings are acceptable because there are cities with 2 words. The output im getting is, the program keeps asking me to enter a city name, no matter what I type in

Comment: @user8799094 Can you update your question with your updated code? Again, it's hard to tell you what's happening with only that explanation. I've given you some code but I have no way of knowing how you've incorporated it.

Comment: @user8799094 ahh you need to remember to reset `isValid` to true at the start of each loop when you look at the next input. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two lines for reading into `city`.

```
    cin >> city;
    getline(cin, city);
```

You need only one of them.

If the name of a city does not contain spaces in them, for your application, use the first one. Otherwise, use the second one. Don't use both.